# Executable read permissions for "Program Files (x86)"

Tags: python, windows, permissions, file-permissions

I made a python program, and froze it to make an executable. The only problem I can see, it that it cannot read/write the contents of several support files. I know that this is  permission error because the `Program Files (x86)` folder is protected. I would prefer to keep my supporting files in the same folder as my executable, so that the users cannot alter them, and so my python program can look locally for them.

I have tried changing the permissions, but I'm not sure which one controls whether my executable can read/write to the local folder.

Comment: Your requirements appear to be self-contradictory; you first say that you want to be able to write to the support files, then that you don't want the users to be able to modify them.  Could you please clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: @HarryJohnston If you read my comment to the answer below, I think that it will clarify somewhat.

Comment: Regular users should have the right to read and execute all files and directories in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`. If you need write access, why can't you use `%ProgramData%`? Its ACL grants full access to the creator/owner of subdirectories and files.

Comment: @eryksun Because I want the _program_ to have write access, and the _user_ to not be able to alter files without an administrator.

Comment: Then create the files in `%ProgramData%` as a different user; only that user or administrators will have write access. Don't write to `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`. That said, unless this is a locked down corporate system, there's nothing you can do to *stop* users from accessing the data. They just need to elevate to an administrator and take ownership of the files.

Comment: @eryksun I don't mind or even dislike the idea of people getting an admin to change things. That's what it's supposed to do. I just don't want a standard user (without admin permissions) to fiddle with this.

Comment: The `%ProgramData%` ACLs default to giving regular users read and execute access (not sure about XP). To get full access the process would need to start elevated, such as by using the `ShellExecute` verb "runas" (not runas.exe; that can't elevate).

Comment: You could instead create a service that's responsible for updating the files. Then have the installer grant the "Local Service" account the right to modify directories and files in the data directory.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want your program to both run and edit files in its current folder. Programs that users invoke run using the user credentials by default.

If you want to prevent users from editing those application config files there are a few tricks:

1. Wrap your app in a DOS batch file. In that batch file use "runas" to start your app using a different account that has both execute and write permissions to those configs. Ensure the invoking user does not have write permissions. That should solve your problem.
2. Instead of flat text files for configs, how about using SQLite? Or encrypt the file. Either way, the same result, the user maybe able to open the file but not know what they are looking at using a typical text editor.

Comment: I have been trying the first one, but it's not working. (If I have two accounts, `Thing 1` and `Thing 2` and `Thing 1` is admin, I can use `runas /user:Thing 1 /savecred "path"` but it does not have the same effect as right-clicking and selecting `run as administrator`. I don't suppose you know why it's doing that?)

Comment: If you're asking how to use runas I believe something like this would work "runas /user:someone /password:aSecret "c:\program fikes\myapp.exe" Yes, the password is visible but it is a hack afterall.

Comment: I know (mostly) how to use runas. `runas /user:someone /savecred "c:\program fikes\myapp.exe"` works well. Only enter the creds one, and they are never visible.

Comment: Does this mean this solution would work for you? Also, I believe using runas and right-click runas are the same thing under the hood. But I suspect we are deviating from the original question.

Comment: That's part of the problem though. If I use a `runas` it runs with the username, but does not have admin privs (even though the account should have admin permissions.)

Comment: Maybe something called UAC is enabled and you may need to relax it. Try to disable UAC and see if that works for you. Not sure if this is a good long term solution but worth trying.